GKE - Troubleshoot Error SSL Certificate Provisioning, Failed Not Visible
I deployed a web application which is hosted both in Google Cloud and in another server. The website, imagine it is "www.example.enterprise.com", has the domain "enterprise.com" in a different server than the subdomain "www.example.enterprise.com", which is in Google Cloud. The website needs 2 ports opened, the 80 and the 3000 to control Google login. I use Google Kubernetes Engine to run the Docker image. I reserved a static IP and I linked it to the subdomain.
I'm struggling to get the SSL certificate work properly as I still get the message that the certificate is provisioning and that the domain status is "Failed Not Visible". I need the website to be HTTPs as it requires Google authentication.
I updated the DNS records today but it has already passed 5h since. How much should I need to wait?
I'd like to know if I have configured the DNS settings correctly, that's why I attach an image from Google Cloud DNS and I also attach the Kubernetes YAML files, which I suppose are correct as I followed the official documentation.

SSL certificate
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: example-managed-cert
  namespace: production
spec:
  domains:
    - www.example.enterprise.com 

Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: example-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: example-managed-cert
    ingressClassName: "gce" # controladador de Ingress integrado de Google Kubernetes Engine
  namespace: production
spec: 
  rules:
  - host: www.example.enterprise.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-service-general
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /oauth2callback
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-service-auth
            port:
              number: 3000

Services
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service-auth
  labels:
    name: example-service-auth
    app: example
  namespace: production
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: example-pod
    app: example
  ports:
    - name: port-general
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service-general
  labels:
    name: example-service-general
    app: example
  namespace: production
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: example-pod
    app: example
  ports:
    - name: port-general
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP


It can take 72 hours , https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting#domain-status

Lat time it happened to me, i did things in this order. Re-created my A record first, then recreated my LB (or just the cert portion). Somehow just updating on existing resources on the fly makes the process longer.

Hi @danyL, I'm aware because I followed the documentation. What I don't know if I set the DNS correctly.

Make sure this is properly completed if you are using cloud dns https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/set-up-dns-records-domain-name

I suppose it is, I just changed the perspective of the project. Back to Cloud Run/Build as with Kubernetes I don't know how to make it work. I have created 2 services on cloud run, one for port 80 and another for port 3000. Will let you know of the outcome.
